# I got a optional object, maybe it is null, so how can we use or judge it?

Tags: java

code like this

```
Optional<String> str = getString();
```

but str maybe is null.

so how can we use this object? Cause I met an NPE exception when I use.

```
str.isPresent()
```

Comment: your getString() didn't return an Optional, it returned null.

Comment: Your `getString()` method should return `Optional.empty()` instead of `null`.

Comment: Please share getString() method code also.

Comment: oh, you mean is we just need to use "null!=str" to judge it?

Comment: no. if you do that, it makes no sense using Optional to begin with. Have your getString() method return an actual Optional.

Comment: but the getString() method is in another component. I can't change it

Comment: in that case, I would stop using that component, since it's not reliable

Comment: emm... I can't stop.

Comment: You should file a bug report! Whoever wrote a method that claims to return Optional but actually returns null, did it wrong. That is one reason to use optional, to avoid null.

Comment: yeah, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `getString()` method call in `Optional`

```
Optional<String> str = Optional.ofNullable(getString());
if (str.isPresent()) {
  // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use Optional depends what you want to with data.

- 1.) If you just want to consume then do like this. 
      `

  ```
  Optional<String> data = getString();
      data.ifPresent(name->{
         System.out.println(name);
      });
  ```

  `
- 2.) If you want to transform or manipute then do

  ```
  data.map(name-> {
          return name+"sample";
     });
  ```
- 3.) If you using java 9 then ,having else with consumer

  ```
  data.ifPresentOrElse(name-> {
         System.out.println(name);
     },()->{
           System.out.println("default");
     });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `getString()` method is returning `null` when it should return `Optional.empty()`. From your comments you suggest that you cannot refactor the `getString()` method.

Your best option here would be to wrap an `Optional` inside an `Optional` to satisfy types like so:

```java
Optional<Optional<String> string = Optional.ofNullable(getString());
```

Here you may then use:

```java
final boolean getStringReturnedValue = string.isPresent(); 
if (getStringReturnedValue) {
    final Optional<String> returnedValue = string.get(); 
    if (returnedValue.isPresent()) {
        final String value = returnedValue.get(); 
        // value usage...
    } else {}
} else {}
```